How to display Lottie Json in specific Folder
I want to display my lottie file, but it is not working :
file Build Action Bundle resource:
      <skia:SKLottieView Grid.Row="0" 
    Source="resource://AppName.Resources.Raw.MyAudios.Effects.userlistening2.json" 
                                                       RepeatMode="Reverse" 
    HorizontalOptions="End" 
    RepeatCount="-1" 
    HeightRequest="30" 
    WidthRequest="30"/>


Since the json file is placed in the subfolder of the  Resource/Raw folder, so you may try setting the source like,
<skia:SKLottieView Grid.Row="0" 

    Source="MyAudios/Effects/userlistening2.json" 
...
/>

The lottie animation will then display. (tested on all platforms).
